# Should I include a condition in my use case diagram?

Tags: uml

I'm practicing drawing a use case diagram for a very simple case, a color-guessing game.

I don't have a picture but it is really simple, with two bubbles for the Player actor to interact with, Play Game and Reset Game.

I would like to add a condition "initialize game" for both use cases, in Play Game it is a precondition and in Reset Game it is a post condition.

It cannot be another use case because the actor would be then System or Game and that's not feasible. Only Player benefits from performing the two current use cases.

How should I include that condition in the use case diagram? Or should I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Use cases are about added value. A single use case shows a single added value brought to its primary actor by the system under consideration. Nothing else! Use cases are a very high business view on the system under consideration.

The conditions you are talking about are part of scenarios you design to implement reaching that added value. And it's hidden in activities inside the use cases.

Other conditions like "user must be logged in" are constraints and attached to use cases somehow. No need to show these on a diagram (though you may if needed).